# How to connect Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mount, windows-phone

I have done the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp 
sudo apt-get update
```

and updated some packages from update manager. After doing above steps I am able to see lumia phone name in file system. But when I try to mount device I am getting following errors:

```
Unable to mount RM-914|Nokia Lumia 520
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:001,010]'
```

Is there any way to solve these problem?

Comment: Hm.  Where did you get your instructions from?

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html 

from above link...

Comment: Am I mistaken, or does that tutorial cover connecting to __Android__ devices, while the Lumia is a __Windows Phone__ device?

Comment: MTP is universal as I understand it.

Comment: have you solved the problem? how? i have this problem too

Comment: @pavankumar That article is outdated as Ubuntu has had Android 4.x plug-and-play for quite awhile...

Answer (score 25):

These are my steps to connect the Nokia Lumia 920 (WP8):

**1. Add the MTP file system in Ubuntu:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp 
sudo apt-get update
```

**2. Make a new udev rule:**

**2.1 Create the rule file:**

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
```

**2.2 Add the following line to the file:**

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="01b1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01b1", SYMLINK+="libmtp", MODE="660", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1"
```

**2.3 Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)**

**3. Reload udev rules:**

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules
```

**4. Connect (or reconnect) the device.**

Comment: Finally..! Saviour..!

Comment: According to that PPA's page, "13.10 (Saucy) and newer versions of Ubuntu contain all of these changes, so you don't need to use this ppa any more." *Unfortunately, even in 14.04 Windows phone won't mount due to this bug*: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1247572 - If you notice this problem, you can select "this affects me" and get notices if/when this is fixed.

Comment: Awesome.. This really worked for Nokia lumnia 625..!

Comment: `idVendor` and `idProduct` are universal? since mines are different but I can connect my phone using this values

Answer (score 3):

Make a new udev rule

`sudo emacs -nw /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`

And add the following line

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="01b1", ATTR{idProduct}=="01b1", SYMLINK+="libmtp",
MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

You need to [refresh the udev rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39371/39841) and unplug/replug the device and it will work. :-)

Comment: Hi, could you explain the steps to make this a useful answer (howto create the file and where).

Comment: I did those steps, except using vi instead of emacs, and kept getting a black screen on reboot on 14.04. If you *do* do this, make sure you know how to login to the ctrl+alt+f2 terminal and move or remove this `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` file you're creating, which fixes the issue!! Unfortunately this answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Plug the phone in, then reboot the phone while it's plugged in.

Worked for me using Ubuntu 13.10 and Lumia 520.

Comment: You mean that you didn't make any other action, just plug and play, right?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check with lock screen disabled?
I remember earlier when I hadn't kept the password lock screen - the file browser used to show the device and I could access it.
However, now that I have kept the password lock screen - the devices are visible but cannot be opened via file browser.

Of course there is one more additional thing: earlier I was using Ubuntu 12.04, now I use 14.04 - so I don't know if the issue is because of change of ubuntu version - I don't think so.