# Cannot access PPA ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, ppa, nokia

I followed the recommendations in the following Q&A to get my phone to work with Ubuntu:

[How to connect Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04)

Unfortunately the installation failed for me. When updating I get the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I get this PPA to work? Is there any other method to access the files and folders on my phone?

Comment: That PPA has no packages for Trusty release.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"13.10 (Saucy) and newer versions of Ubuntu contain all of these changes, so you don't need to use this ppa any more.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~langdalepl/+archive/ubuntu/gvfs-mtp"

Run these commands in an open terminal to fix the problem.

```
sudo rm langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Plug the phone in and reboot. This method also works to mount USB connected devices as well as SD cards.

Comment: Thank you very much it works well. But we need to reboot the machine every time when we plug the phone? Once I plug the phone reboot the machine it works well, again I unplug and plug the phone I cannot access to the memory.

Comment: Sometimes you can mount devices manually using commands like `sudo mount` just specify the mount point "/media"and to determine the device to mount, you can run `lsblk` to show the available devices. Also, devices sometimes show up in your file manager and to mount them, all you have to do is select the device and it will then mount and you can access the files. If you accept this answer please click the icon to the left to mark it as answered. thanks!

Comment: I've must say that mtp is so slow that it's really better to look into other options such as ssh to transfer files.