# How to connect a Nokia Lumia 730 to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mtp, nokia, windows-phone

I have trouble to connect my new Nokia 730 to Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried some solution I found searching WEB (like this one: [How to connect Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04)) but nothing helped. My File-Manager Thunar (I am using XFCE) shows also that something is mounted, but when I click on each icon, following error appears:

In German:

> Der Datenträger »Lumia 730 Dual SIM (RM-1040)« konnte nicht eingehängt werden. Fehler beim Initialisieren der Kamera: -1: Unspecified error.

English (automatically translated from askubuntu):

> The disk » Lumia 730 Dual SIM (RM -1040 ) " could not be mounted. Failed to initialize the camera : -1: Unspecified error

The Nokia is plugged in but recognized wrongly, as a camera!

With Android I had no problems and the two icons in Thunar pointed respectively to the phone and to the card. The MTP worked with Android and I don't think is a missing MTP tools. I tried and installed all I needed, but with Windows phone does not work correctly.

Can anyone help me and give me a solution?

My Systemlog shows following informations:

```
 kernel: [  461.933996] usb 3-10: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
 kernel: [  461.965116] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0421,  idProduct=06fc
 kernel: [  461.965125] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 kernel: [  461.965130] usb 3-10: Product: Lumia 730 Dual SIM (RM-1040)
 kernel: [  461.965134] usb 3-10: Manufacturer: Microsoft
 kernel: [  461.965138] usb 3-10: SerialNumber: 1100000058BE4FB90000000000000000
 colord: Device added: sysfs-Microsoft-Lumia_730_Dual_SIM__RM-1040_
 colord: Device added: sysfs-(null)
```