# my windows phone is not getting detected on ubuntu 14.04, how can i make it happen?

Tags: windows-phone

My Lumis 730 having windows 8.1 is not being detected on my ubuntu 14.04 when connected via usb, kindly provide me a solution to make it work!!

Comment: Add the results of `lsusb` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing mtp-tools and mtpfs.

In terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> enter

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

hit enter, reboot after install and try again. Your phone must be unlocked to gain access to the file system.

Hope this helps, good Luck!

[edit]
If it does not help, there is a more complex solution to this problem (create an udev rule) here:
[How to connect Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04)

You won't need to add the repository they are speaking of, since mtp support is already present in 14.04 (was not in 12.04)
[/edit]