# Not able connect my Nokia Lumia 530 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, mtp, windows-phone

I am trying to connect my Nokia Lumia 530 mobile phone using a USB cable in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version.
I have already tried the solution given in the first answer of the question 
[How to connect Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04/484077#484077).
But, it is not working for me.
When I tried this solution my phone was displayed in the fie manager,but when i tried to mount it, it gave me an error "unable to access nokia lumia 530 dual SIM(rm 1010)
no mtp devices found".
Please someone help me as soon as possible.

Comment: hey please someone help me in this issue