# how to mount windows phone in Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, windows-phone

In Ubuntu, windows phone are not being detected. How can I mount it using the terminal?

The PPA provided in this link [How to connect Nokia Lumia 520 to Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367927/how-to-connect-nokia-lumia-520-to-ubuntu-12-04). is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Samba and connect the phone via USB it should be automatically detected

Comment: My phone already detected, but the ubuntu says "unable to open MTP device" https://s.kaskus.id/images/2017/02/01/5859183_20170201014758.png